# CameraOffset and increasecameraOffset in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the job of that scripts in
Javascript

```
CameraOffset
```

```
increaseCameraOffset
```

And are they related to device camera or the camera movements in apps and games or something else

I want an explanation about how they work and what they do

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at our [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Those functions are not native javscript. If you use a library, please [edit] your question and tag accordingly.

Comment: @0stone0 even if they are not native javascript i just want to know what they do ??